# Creating JSON nested file structure

Tags: json

I am trying to add year and month to a JSON file so I can group all parties and events into a month without having to place this information in each event but when I add it at the top of file it won't parse I am having a syntax issue somewhere here.

```
{    
"year": 2023,
"month": 12
 {
  "Parties": [
    {
      "Event1": 67.7,
      "Event2": 5.1,
      "Event3": 3.3    
    },        
    {
       "Event1": 89.7,
       "Event2": 4.3,
       "Event3": 3.2        
    },
    {
       "Event1": 69.3,
       "Event2": 4.2,
       "Event3": 0.0        
    }
   ]
 }
}
```

Comment: What you have is invalid JSON.  (Well, an invalid object structure, but presumably this is raw text to be parsed as JSON.)  There's no comma after the `month` property, and no name for the property after it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo (comma is missing after month) and extra curly bracket `{` you have.

The working JSON is:

```
{
  "Year": 2023,
  "Month": 12,
  "Parties": [
    {
      "Event1": 67.7,
      "Event2": 5.1,
      "Event3": 3.3
    },
    {
      "Event1": 89.7,
      "Event2": 4.3,
      "Event3": 3.2
    },
    {
      "Event1": 69.3,
      "Event2": 4.2,
      "Event3": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

or if you want to use nested JSON, then add a property name before "Parties"

```
{
  "Year": 2023,
  "Month": 12,
  "PartyData": {
    "Parties": [
      {
        "Event1": 67.7,
        "Event2": 5.1,
        "Event3": 3.3
      },
      {
        "Event1": 89.7,
        "Event2": 4.3,
        "Event3": 3.2
      },
      {
        "Event1": 69.3,
        "Event2": 4.2,
        "Event3": 0
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this property since its a top level property does it have a specific name? I just wanted to do one file so I can figure it out for another 20K files. Am I adding a header property or something.

Comment: If you are asking about `"PartyData"`, it could be any name you can use.

Comment: Well yes but what the more general technical name if I were to google this particular property is what I am asking.  What would I bee googling? Make sense.

Comment: I would like to add this property programmatically in python but I dont even know what it is called to google it

Comment: It is JSON property name only